# SPFx Replacement for Script Editor Web Part

Tags: javascript, spfx-webparts, sp.js, modern-experience, modern-pages

So I was having a play around with the new Modern Experience site pages and while it's pretty slick and looks great (as well as fixing the issues with container layouts being a royal pain to change about), dissapointed the Embed web part only allows iframes and not Javascript.

Did a bit of reading up and it seems MS are using this to push everyone to using SPFx, which I did have a play about with but it seems horrendously complicated (at least for me right now while keeping up with everything else). As far as I can tell, you can wrap whatever JS you want in an SPFx WP, so an idea occurred to me...

Would it be feasible to create a basic WP in SPFx with no real configuration or WP properties, and just use this as a template to insert whatever custom JS I need to run? If so, what's the best way to go about this?

Basically looking for a 'as little config as possible' way of getting JS onto Modern pages; the sooner we get used to this the better as I feel there's going to be a lot of clients within the next while needing their Classic pages updated when MS eventually ditch Classic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This web part has already been [created](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/dev/samples/react-script-editor). but read [General thoughts on a modern script editor webpart](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/480) before you use it.

Comment: Nice one, thanks Per. I did think it pretty likely some other clever clogs had beat me to it. :)