# Hide "+ Add" in iFrame - News Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, newsfeed, iframe

I have a new modern news webpart in classic SP Online and I need to hide the "+ Add"

Could you explain how this can be done with JS?
[image: Iframe]

[image: Script]

I have the following code, how can this be used to not load the "+ Add"

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var f=$('#iframeID')
        f.load(function(){ 
            f.contents().find('.feedback_88fc6c94').hide(); 
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding this selector: `document.querySelector("button[data-automation-id='newsAddButton'").style.display = "none"`

Comment: Would the selector be in the script part of the script? or in the iframe? As i have place an id tag in the iframe and loading a separate JS script

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var f=$('#newsAddButton')
        f.load(function(){ 
            f.contents().find('.feedback_88fc6c94').hide(); 
        })
    })
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Customizing the modern sharepoint with custom JS/HTML/Whatever is totally against best practices (established by MS).

You have 2 options here if you want to stick to the best practices (im pretty sure you cant customize it anyway).

1. Create a SPFX Webpart with the same functionality as the news webpart - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part
2. Create a SPFX Extension to customize that webpart (i dont think it works on customizing webparts, but i'm not sure) - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions.

EDIT: You could also create a custom JS webpart (like the old content editor) or use a open sourced one. You can read more in this answer here -> [SPFx Replacement for Script Editor Web Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224944/spfx-replacement-for-script-editor-web-part)